# Videos on Views Slideshow start at the same time (Drupal 7)

Tags: javascript, views

I have a slider on my homepage created with views slideshow.

When I only have images on this slider, it works perfectly.

However when I have videos only (these videos are not from Youtube but are uploaded from my drive (format .mov)), as soon as the slider starts, both videos are playing... I can see my first video and there is the sound of the second video on the background...

Has anyone ever experienced this before?

Could you help me with any solution please?

Many thanks

PS: To read the videos I am using jwplayer.